# Windows Authentication prompt username field autopopulates and cannot be changed

Tags: browser, windows-7, sharepoint-2010, internet-explorer-8, windows-authentication

I have a website that uses Windows Authentication to authenticate its users. Normally when a user accesses the site on an IE browser the username field is populated with the computers domain name and user name. This is usually incorrect and the user enters the correct username and their password and can access the site.

I have a user now on Windows 7 IE8(I beleive) and the username field in the credential prompt is being autopopulated with domain\userName except the username is incorrect and we cannot change it. The user is unable to log into the site because of this. Has anyone experienced this before? Does anyone know why the username field cannot be changed? Solutions I have tried:

1. Clearing cache and stored form data/passwords etc
2. Site is in users trusted sites. So I had the user change the settings to "Prompt for username and password" but the prompt still comes up with the username autopopulated and does not let her change it.

I have never run into this before. Our users do not have any issue logging in, its just this one corporate location that was just set up and is running Windows 7(Rest of the company is under Windows XP)  If it matters this is a sharepoint 2010 web application
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I have an entire group of users with this problem. Im willing to bet this would not be an issue in a different browser but they need to be able to use IE for application compatibility reasons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by doing the following:

Go to Start, Control Panel, User Accounts, then click Manage Your Credentials, and look for the credentials to your site, if they are there Modify and “Remove from vault” ( I suppose you could Edit them to the correct credentials but I just removed it and it did not prompt her).

She had the wrong credentials stored there. Im not sure why clearing the cache and passwords from the internet options didnt work but this did.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a user where the domain stored with the credentials could not be changed. This is the only item online I could find even close to my problem. The user saw "user-pcdomain\localusername" auto entered in the form.  He tried to correct it with "workdomain\workusername" but got a message saying "Please enter a user name and password".  Eventually we realized that his system was sending "user-pcdomain\workdomain" as his username.    I've never seen a login misfire like that.

In his case he did not have his credentials stored but needed to add credentials - "workdomain\workusername" - for all of the domains he needed to access.

The point is - to expand on the answer - that IE or Windows 7 or both will store credentials incorrectly on rare occasions and the solution is be creative about adding\editing\remove credentials with Manage Your Credentials